# HTML link to specific pages in PDF

Tags: hyperlink, pdf

I have looked around the web and have found that appending `#page=??` to the end of a PDF link will automatically take the visitor to that specific page in the PDF file.

I was wondering if this is still best practice as it doesn't seem to be working for me (Chrome on Windows 7). Also, all the articles I have found so far date back to 2006-2008, have things changed recently?

Comment: It's working for me on IE8+, Firefox 20 and Chrome

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is still valid code but it may require that some version of Acrobat (Reader, Pro, etc) be installed as a plugin on the browser in order for it to work as expected.  Since multiple commonly-used browsers now have a built-in reader (Chrome, Safari for iOS are the big two that come to mind) support for direct page linking is somewhat spotty now.  You can still do it...the worst case scenario is that the PDF just opens to the first page for those users but I would advise to just leave off the direct page link. If the page is that important, extract it to a separate PDF and link to that.